# MySQL special characters when doing a SELECT shows others results without special characters

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, character-encoding, special-characters

We have a table with a couple hundreds tags. Some of them have special characters (spanish characters). And some of those tags might contain the same letters, but not exactly the same string with and without the special characters.

Let me show an example:

```
 select * from tags where name = 'olga tañón';
```

I would expect to get in the result the specific row that has "olga tañón", but instead MySQL is giving me as a results:

```
 olga tañón
 olga tañon
 olga tanon
```

Notice that is the same letters, but some of them have the special characters (ñ and ó) and others don't. The table encoding is latin1. We're using Rails 3.2 and MySQL 5.x

Here is an example code

```
 Tag.where(:name => "olga tañón")
 Tag Load (94.6ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` WHERE `tags`.`name` = 'olga tañón'
 => [#<Tag id: 57502, name: "olga tañón">, #<Tag id: 75642, name: "olga tañon">, #<Tag id: 114622, name: "olga tanon">]
```

What could we do if we want to get the exactly string returned in the SELECT result when I run a query with special characters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to specify the collation - look at this
http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/mysqls-character-sets-and-collations-demystified and this
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-collation-charset.html
and this
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-collation-effect.html